# Webpack server configuration + external libs

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have the following webpack configuration file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const LiveReloadPlugin = require('webpack-livereload-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:2000', // WebpackDevServer host and port
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', // "only" prevents reload on syntax errors
    './app/index.tsx'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  devtool: 'source-map',

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'ts'],
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'app')
      }
    ],

    preLoaders: [
      'source-map-loader'.
      {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'source-map-loader'}
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {from: './app/index.html', to: './dist/index.html'}
    ]),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  builds.
  externals: {
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
  }
};
```

and here is my server configuration:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const config = require('./webpack.config');

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
  contentBase: './dist',
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  hot: true,
  historyApiFallback: true,
  open: 'http://localhost:2000'
}).listen(2000, 'localhost', function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  console.log('Listening at http://localhost:2000/');
});
```

I want to be able to access the application from root path: `http://localhost:2000` and not `http://localhost:2000/dist`.

One more thing, is there any way to move all the external dependancies from node_modules to `dist` with webpack (without the need to include the `script` tag in the `index.html` file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all for set application start point you need to set publicPath to `"/"` or `publicPath: 'http://localhost:2000'`
Your second question

### Is there any way to move all the external dependancies from node_modules to dist with webpack?

### Yes

You can use different file just for external modules and bundle that file. You don't need to take care of index.html file let webpack plugin HtmlWebpackPlugin take care of it.

First step set entry points for your app

```
entry: {
        'vendors': './src/vendors.ts',//your external libraries 
        'app': './src/main.ts' //your app
}
```

and out put

```
output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js'//this will generate two different files app.js, vendor.js
}
```

### How to add [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin)?

Add this in you plugins

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
     template: "./src/index.html",
     minify:false
})
```

### Now it will place script tags for you

Comment: The first issue was solved, thanks. Regarding the second one, how webpack knows what will go to vendor.js file - by adding the code in the entry object I got the following error: `Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./app/vendors.ts in /Users/vioffe/dev/live-symetric
`

Comment: You need a vendor.ts or whatever type of file you are using in app fonder which will contain your dependencies and webpack will bundle all of them in one

Comment: so should I remove the external object from webpack, and add all required vendor files to the entry object?

Comment: Yes that is how it should be.

Comment: But index.js imports react files so it seems that they are bundled already in the bundle.js file in my dist folder. Though I am getting ;Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined`

Comment: Files you just need to load in browser from other vendors can ve included there but files you need to work with Like react you need to import them into your index.js.

Answer (score 1):

on you server configuration change your `public path` to

```
publicPath: '/',
```